# Problem in installing YouTube unity lens

Tags: installation, unity, lenses, youtube, scopes

I was trying to installing YouTube lens and scope from Ubuntu.

I typed the following in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/lenses
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lens-video scope-youtube
```

The output is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lens-video
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i have tried and got as you got . But in my search i found that , that package was not available for Ubuntu 12.04 .

[Click Here](https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/lenses?field.series_filter=precise)

as I have seen just installing `scope-youtube` will be enough .
[image][image]

Comment: thanxxx its working now i installed yavol and now its working...